# window.print() not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the below code, the `window.print()` function not working in Chrome.what to do?

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="itemin"> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Name" size="20"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="qtyin"> <input type="num" placeholder="quantity" size="20" id="qty"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="rsin"> <input type="text" placeholder="prize" size="20" id="rs"> <button onclick="mul()" id="add">add </button> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="amtin"> <input type="text"  size="20" id="amt">  <input type="text" size="7" id="total"> <button onclick="print()" id="print"> print </div>
</div>

<script>
    function print()
    {
        window.print();
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: What happens? Is there any output on the chrome console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Congratulations, you caused a StackOverflow!

This code:

```
function print() {
    window.print();
}
```

is same as writing:

```
window.print = function {
    window.print();
}
```

Basically you overwrote the native [`window.print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) function with your own function that calls `window.print` recursively. The solution is simple... remove your function and simply:

```
<button onclick="window.print()" id="print">print</button>
```

Or this:

```
<button onclick="myPrintFunction()" id="print">print</button>
<script>
    function myPrintFunction() {
        // do something maybe
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: omg...i was like why does it keep calling itself in chrome debugger....thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is because of it went on infinite loop. The code `onclick="print()"` will automatically call the `window.print()`.

Either you change the function name or remove the print function. It will work.

Comment: thank you suresh ponnukalai & salman A. Both of your idea works.

Answer (score 0):

Just call window.print() in the onclick of button. No need to define a function for it.

```
<body>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-3" id="itemin"> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Item Name" size="20"> </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2" id="qtyin">
   <input type="num" placeholder="quantity" size="20" id="qty"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3" id="rsin"> <input type="text" placeholder="prize" size="20" id="rs"> <button onclick="mul()" id="add">Add </button> </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3" id="amtin">
   <input type="text"  size="20" id="amt">
   <input type="text" size="7" id="total">
   <button onclick="window.print()" id="print">Print</button>
    </div>
</body>
```